# What is the best angular 7 hook to handle ViewChildren

Tags: javascript, angular, hook

I have an Angular 7 application in which I'm trying to handle a text input in ngAfterViewChecked().

The text input is a node in a mat-tree. It's visibility depends on an ngIf condition. If that condition is not met, I display a span instead. Essentially, if the user double clicks on a node in the tree (a span element), it becomes a text input so that the user can edit the text:

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="nestedDataSource" [treeControl]="nestedTreeControl">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node">
    <li>
      <span *ngIf="!node.isInput" (dblClick)="nodeDoubleClicked(node)">{{ node.name }}</span>
      <input *ngIf="node.isInput" #nodeNameInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="node.name" (blur)="doneEditting(node)" (keypress)="keyPressed($event, node)" />
    </li>
  </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNestedChild">
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle>
      <mat-icon>
        {{ nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right' }}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span *ngIf="!node.isInput" (dblClick)="nodeDoubleClicked(node)">{{ node.name }}</span>
    <input *ngIf="node.isInput" #nodeNameInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="node.name" (blur)="doneEditting(node)" (keypress)="keyPressed($event, node)" />
    <ul [class.collapsed]="!nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node)">
      <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
    </ul>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

When the user double clicks on a node, I not only want it to turn into an input text, I want it to gain focus and select the text inside. In order to do this, I have to get the native element and call .focus() and .select() on it. In order to get the native element, I have to use ViewChildren (where the input is tagged with #nodeNameInput as you can see in the code snippet above). And finally, I need to hook into ngAfterViewChecked() in order to be sure that the QueryList of the ViewChildren is ready.

Here is the code for the component:

```
@ViewChildren('nodeNameInput') nodeNameInputs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

...

ngAfterViewChecked() {
  if (this.nodeNameInputs && this.nodeNameInputs.length) {
    this.nodeNameInputs.first.nativeElement.focus();
    this.nodeNameInputs.first.nativeElement.select();
  }
}
```

I've ensured that there is only ever one node being edited at a time, so it's safe to use first rather than search through nodeNameInputs to find the one to put in focus and select the text.

This seems to work, but there is a problem. It seems like for every key stroke, ngAfterViewChecked() is also called. What this means is that as the user is editing the text for the node, it gets re-selected for every key stroke. This results in the text the user enters being overwritten on every key stroke.

I have a workaround to this problem:

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  if (this.nodeNameInputs && this.nodeNameInputs.length) {
    this.nodeNameInputs.first.nativeElement.focus();
    if (!this.keyStroked) {
      this.nodeNameInputs.first.nativeElement.select();
    }
  }
}
```

...where keyStroked is set in the keyPressed handler and set to false in the blur handler.

But I'm wondering if there is another hook that can reliably be used to focus the input and select its text while not responding to key strokes. I chose ngAfterViewChecked because a test showed that it was the only hook in which nodeNameInputs was consistently ready every time (i.e. this.nodeNameInputs.length was always 1). But maybe I missed certain hooks.

My workaround seems like a hack. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Just add a  boolen var into child comp. Start with proper state. Bind visibility to that var and let mode control it based on element or data events. E.g. a subscription to data complete would allow view var to be true which changes view.

Comment: Let model control everything. Its better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a focus directive and place that on the input you want focused, you wont have to worry about life cycle events.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[focus]'
})
export class FocusDirective {

  constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
    elm.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

and use it

```
<input focus>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnjw1s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I'm unfamiliar with how directives work. This gives me a clue. I will look into this and see if it works for my purpose.